# Why my Enum not working to show the colored background?

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

The Background Color is not showing when I pass in the BGColor Prop dynamically in next.js + Tailwind app

I tried passing in the prop for my component but wouldn't show the color

`<Title title='This is HOME' description='lorem ipsum'bgColor={BGColor.Teal} />`

// Home page

```
'use client';
import React from 'react';
import Title, { BGColor } from '../components/Title';

const home = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <main>
        <Title
          title='This is HOME'
          description='lorem ipsum '
          bgColor={BGColor.Teal}
        />
      </main>
    </>
  );
};

export default home;
```

//MyComponent

```
'use client';

export enum BGColor {
  Red = 'red',
  Slate = 'slate',
  Teal = 'teal',
}

interface TitleProps {
  title?: string;
  description?: string;
  isHalf?: boolean;
  bgColor?: BGColor;
}

export default function Title({
  title,
  description,
  isHalf,
  bgColor,
}: TitleProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <main
        className={`text-white flex justify-between m-5 py-3 px-10 rounded-lg
        ${isHalf && 'w-1/2'} 
        bg-${bgColor}-400`}
      >
        <div>
          <h1>{title}</h1>
          <p> {description}</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button>Button</button>
          <button>Button</button>
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  );
}
```

can't figure out why this is not working? All the other props are doing what its supposed to except the BGColor

Comment: What is the actually applied class? Inspect the element using the browser devtools. That will give you an idea of what exactly is not working.

Comment: Aside: Generally, it's a bad idea to use enums (they're confusing and error prone, and the TS team admit they were a mistake). Rather just use a plain object.

Answer (score 2):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could consider using full class names in definitions, like:

```
export enum BGColor {
  Red = 'bg-red-400',
  Slate = 'bg-slate-400',
  Teal = 'bg-teal-400',
}

export default function Title({
  title,
  description,
  isHalf,
  bgColor,
}: TitleProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <main
        className={`text-white flex justify-between m-5 py-3 px-10 rounded-lg
        ${isHalf && 'w-1/2'} 
        ${bgColor}`}
      >
        {/* … */}
      </main>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Or whitelisting them in the Tailwind config.